# Webview open link in app loads main page, not link

Tags: android, webview

When the webView application installed touch on links example.com are detected from browser, but when choose open in app, opens app and loads main page, not link

```
<intent-filter>
   <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
   <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>
<intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
    <data android:scheme="@string/scheme" />
</intent-filter>
 <intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
    <data android:scheme="https" android:host="@string/domain" />
    <data android:scheme="https" android:host="@string/domain_nw" />
    <data android:scheme="http" android:host="@string/domain" />
     <data android:scheme="http" android:host="@string/domain_nw" />
 </intent-filter>
```

Links skatehype://example.com is working (tested but not used yet)
Links https://example.com/xxx opens app in main page (or any link)

If I try to set path or pathPrefix
`android:pathPrefix="/.*"`
Causes browser don't ask for "open in app"

How can I redirect to the right url when open in app link?

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        super.getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_PROGRESS);

        /*...*/

        if (getIntent().getData() != null) {
            String path     = getIntent().getDataString();
            aswm_view(path);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Set a breakpoint to the "path" variable and see what output you are getting!

Answer (score 0):

Solved!
I was loading start_url when application loads. Justa ask for .getData before it.

```
public void run() {
  if (getIntent().getData() != null) {
    String path = getIntent().getDataString();
    aswm_view(path);
  } else {
    aswm_view(ASWV_URL); //Rendering the default URL
  }
}
```